# How can I install driver for usb 48f:7601 Ralink on Ubutnu 22.04? Kernel Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64

Tags: wireless, usb

When I put the comand sudo tail /var/log/syslog I get the following

```
Aug 14 00:53:56 luciano-desktop kernel: [ 3462.421803] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop kernel: [ 3462.582955] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop kernel: [ 3462.584374] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: loading /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin failed with error -22
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop kernel: [ 3462.584381] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -22
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop kernel: [ 3462.584991] mt7601u: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -22
Aug 14 00:47:19 luciano-desktop rtkit-daemon[751]: Supervising 7 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1"
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1"
Aug 14 00:53:57 luciano-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

I have tried with procedures applied to other kernels but they have not worked

Ubuntu version Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64

When I used `lsusb`, I get the following:
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

Answer (score 1):

You already have a driver, *mt7601u*, but you are evidently missing firmware. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, it worked